# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:40) react fixed data table

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs, fixed-data-table

We have a react app with this `OurController` item. The `OurController` is working fine. Adding the following code from an example breaks entire app, no page will render in the browser:

```
const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}
  </Cell>
);
```

Beginning of file is

```
var FixedDataTable = require('fixed-data-table');
var React = require('react');

const Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
const Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
const Cell = FixedDataTable.Cell;

const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}
  </Cell>
);

class OurDataTable extends React.Component {
```

As soon as I comment it out, all is well, but I want to follow tutorial as closely as possible

The error is like

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:40)
const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, {issue is here}...props}) => (
```

with an arrow pointing to `...props`, seeming like it doesn't understand `...` (arrow points to the first dot)

[image]

The guide is this snippet for `fixed-data-table`:

https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/examples/ObjectDataExample.js

I know the entire file is important in general but I promise the code works as expected until adding `TextCell`. We have certain babel loaders but I did not see the fixed data table ask for more:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve('./public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

An express server is configured likewise and is working (hot reload, etc)

We have used ES6 and working as in things like

`class OurDataTable extends React.Component {`

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but i think, issue is with spread operator `...`, You need to configure `Babel` to use the `transform-object-rest-spread plugin`.

Follow this link to install it: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: boom, figured it was some odd loader. thanks mayank I check